# Android custom media controller using vidtry

Tags: android, android-video-player

I want to use a custom media controller in my Android app and therefore looking at the vidtry code (http://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry), especially Player.java:

The sample works fine as it comes. But I want the sample to play the fixed video automatically on app startup (so I don't want to enter a URL).
I added:

```
 @Override
 public void onResume() {
  super.onResume(); 
  address.setText("/sdcard/mydata/category/1/video_agkkr6me.mp4");
  go.setEnabled(true);
  onGo.onClick(go);  
 }
```

Strange thing here is that if I run the app, the audio of the video plays but the image doesn't show. Everything else works fine (progress bar, etc.). I can't figure out the difference between the manual click on the go-button and the programmatic one. I looked at the code and didn't see any difference that might occur between manual and programmatic click.

I checked if any elements (esp. surface) might be hidden, but it's not. I even tried a

```
surface.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
surface.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

in case of some issue with the redrawing, but no difference.

The video image does show when I manually hit the go button, but just not on start up automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seemed that the surface wasn't ready at onResume yet. Implementing SurfaceHolder.Callback  and then starting the video from surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) solves the problem.

Comment: I've whitnessed the same behaviour myself.

Comment: you are a life saver Mathias.